# Why did Jake apologize in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, playing-with-fire

In *Playing with Fire* (2019) there's the following conversation:

> Bill: I was working a Class F in southern Idaho, and someone forwards me a video of one of my smokejumpers being pulled into a Huey.
>
> Jake: Sir, about that...I apologize.

It doesn't make any sense in Jake's reply to apologize. Why does he do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Because he thought the commander was going to say he'd done something wrong.

So his first instinct was to get in front of the potential rebuke and apologize.

As it turns out that was not the opinion of the commander. In fact he thought it was great PR for the fire department,